# Why TCHAR value changes if Multi-Byte Character Set used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, character-encoding

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    TCHAR x = 0x80;
    printf("%X", x);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use "Character Set = Use Multi-Byte Character Set" in Visual Studio project settings, I get output:

> FFFFFF80

The same code if built with "Character Set = Use Unicode Character Set", it gives correct output:

> 80

Why is this different behavior?

Comment: `%X` is for `unsigned int`.  You are lying to `printf` by providing a `char`.

Comment: I'm getting 0xFFFFFF80 with both settings. Which VS dou you have? Which Platfom toolset do you use? But anyway it's UB.

Comment: [Warnings when compiled under gcc](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeffd07c6590a0d4)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie with respect to your first comment: 
Then why not the same behavior with char x = 0x79; printf("%X", x); 
I am lying to printf again and it should give FFFFFF79.

With respect to your second comment: okay I get it. This is because of overflow.

Comment: @Jabberwocky
I am using Visual Studio 2017 (v141). Well, if it is Undefined Behavior then that's the answer I guess. I get it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes you are right. sorry my bad. I used TCHAR actually. Edited now.
So, with TCHAR it shows two different behaviors with two different settings. My question was mainly that. What is the difference it is making in these two settings and how that is affecting my code? Is this because of Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @BarshanDas OK, then it's a totally different story. But you're stilly lying to `printf`.

Comment: This happens:  if x is a w_char(16 bit value) then 0x80 is positive (it's actually 0x0080. If it's a char, then 0x80 is negative and sign extension happens when the char 0x80 is promoted to int. Actually it's not UB. TCHAR is either char or w_char depending on the "character set" setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multibyte character set : TCHAR stands for char . In the Microsoft compiler, char is an 8-bit type.

For Unicode character set: TCHAR stands for wchar_t .In the Microsoft compiler, wchar_t represents a 16-bit wide character

You are seeing the "FFFFFF" because char is signed on your system. In C, functions such as printf will promote all integers smaller than int to int. Since char is an integer , your chars are being promoted to int via sign-extension.

Since "80" have a leading 1-bit , they are being sign-extended.

I suggest you could try to use the following code to mask out the upper bits and keep only the lower 8 bits that you want.

```
    printf("%X", x & 0xFF);
```